# React element onClick not working with Shadow DOM in Firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, shadow-dom, react-dom

I have an add-on with following code, inserted using shadow dom inside main page.

```
  <Action
    icon="chat"
    onClick={() => {
        //something to do
    }}
  />
```

This onClick work perfectly in Chrome but not in Firefox.

I am attaching shadow as follows:

```
  let host = document.createElement('article')
  let root = host.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
```

Comment: what is `host`?

Comment: Yeah, going to need a little more info about how/why you are using the shadow DOM here, and how it is impacting the Action component.

Comment: @WillJenkins Element to which shadow is attached. Updated my question too.

Comment: Could you show the code where you render the component into the shadow-dom?